# SQL - Make a function that return lines of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I'm using Mysql and I'm trying to make a function that is able to return me all of the lines of a table if the id is ok.
that's my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lesPieces(varchar)
RETURNS TABLE my_table
DECLARE
    ligne piece%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR ligne IN
        SELECT *
        FROM piece;
            LOOP
                RETURN NEXT ligne;
            END LOOP;
    RETURN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But Mysql returns me :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax near : 
'FUNCTION lesPieces(varchar)
RETURNS TABLE my_table
DECLARE
    ligne piece%ROWTY' at line 1
```

Have you got an idea ?
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EDIT :
Thanks to @Slasko for this help : 
You sure REPLACE is command ? should it be something like DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS [function_name]; DELIMITER $$ CREATE FUNCTION [function_name(function_parameter)] ?
So I just removed the "OR REPLACE" but now the error is :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax near : 'varchar) RETURNS SETOF piece AS' at line 1
```

Comment: You sure `REPLACE` is command ? should it be something like `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS [function_name];
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION  [function_name(function_parameter)]` ?

Comment: I don't see `DELIMITER $$` at the start of your code and `DELIMITER ;` at the end. Are you using it?

Comment: Yep, i'm using it :'(

Answer (score 0):

This create function has many issues. For e-g  RETURNS can have possible values {STRING|INTEGER|REAL|DECIMAL} as per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html

Please refer below link for examples
http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/create-function-examples.html